# i2cdetect shows random addresses for VL53L0 device

Tags: pi-3b+, i2c, sensor

I plugged the [VL53L0 distance sensor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002027761981.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3e524c4dKsjNMo) to RPi 3B+ onto the I2C pins. Specifically, red to 3v3 Power, white to SDA, blue to SDC, and black to the ground (I left yellow and green unplugged).

Now, everytime I run the `i2cdetect -y 1` command, there are different and random addresses shown, but I would expect only one address. The following commands are run less than second after each other.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- 04 -- 06 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1d -- 1f 
20: -- -- 22 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 39 3a -- 3c -- -- -- 
40: 40 -- -- -- -- 45 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5c 5d -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- 75 76 77                         
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- 07 -- -- -- -- -- 0d -- -- 
10: 10 -- -- 13 -- -- 16 -- -- 19 -- -- -- -- -- 1f 
20: -- -- 22 -- -- -- -- -- 28 -- 2a -- -- -- 2e -- 
30: -- -- -- -- 34 -- -- -- -- -- 3a 3b 3c -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- 45 46 -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5a 5b 5c -- 5e -- 
60: 60 -- -- -- -- 65 -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0b 0c 0d -- -- 
10: 10 -- 12 -- 14 -- 16 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 2c -- -- 2f 
30: -- 31 -- -- 34 -- -- -- 38 -- 3a -- 3c 3d -- -- 
40: -- 41 -- 43 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5b 5c 5d -- 5f 
60: -- -- -- -- -- 65 -- 67 -- -- 6a -- -- 6d 6e 6f 
70: -- 71 72 -- -- 75 -- --
```

I know that the I2C bus is working because when I plug in a different sensor it works fine. What I am not sure about is if the sensor needs 3V or 5V (it's not clear from the guide), however, I get the same output for both options.

Thanks for any help, also if I should use a different bus and wiring.

[image: Wiring of the sensor]
[image: Overall setup]

Comment: Does it work?  Ignore i2cdetect, does it actually return sensible values when it is addressed?

Comment: Using python lib and [this file](https://github.com/pimoroni/VL53L0X-python/blob/master/python/VL53L0X_example.py) gives me `API Status: -20 : Control Interface Error`. Not sure what address should I read, it uses 0x29 as default.